# Why does this Javascript not work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to manipulate a date with some simple Javascript. The code is as follows:

```
var newDate = new Date("2013-07-23" + " 12:00:00");
console.log(newDate.toString());
newDate = new Date(newDate.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
console.log(newDate.toString());
var date = newDate.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + newDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
console.log(date);
```

Essentially, I am converting

```
2013-07-23 -> Jul 22 2013 12:00:00 GMT+1000 -> 2013-07-22
```

It works fine in Chrome, you can test the code via this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxZVx/). It always returns

```
"Invalid Date"
"Invalid Date"
"NaN-aN-aN"
```

For the three `console.logs` in Firefox, but:

```
Tue Jul 23 2013 12:00:00 GMT+1000 (E. Australia Standard Time)
Mon Jul 22 2013 12:00:00 GMT+1000 (E. Australia Standard Time) 
2013-07-22
```

For Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your date format should be "IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamp" and there's some cross-browser inconsistency if it's not.

Read about it here: http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html

But basically - you should just replace '`-`' with '`/`' to make it work on any existing browser

Answer (score 2):

The spec does not require that the date format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` be parsed:

`new Date`:
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2

> Parse v as a date, in exactly the same manner as for the parse method

(essentially, the same result as `Date.parse(...)`)

`Date.parse`: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2

> The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format (15.9.1.15). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats. Unrecognisable Strings or dates containing illegal element values in the format String shall cause Date.parse to return NaN.

Date Time String Format: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15

> The format is as follows: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

There is **no guarantee that any other format works**, including `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

You can always construct a conformant date string:

```
var newDate = new Date("2013-07-23" + "T12:00:00.000Z");
console.log(newDate.toString());
newDate = new Date(newDate.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
console.log(newDate.toString());
var date = newDate.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + newDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox:

```
new Date("2013-07-23 12:00:00").toString()   // Invalid
new Date("2013-07-23T12:00:00").toString()   // Local noon
new Date("2013-07-23T12:00:00Z").toString()  // UTC noon
new Date("2013/07/23 12:00:00").toString()   // Local noon
```

In Chrome:

```
new Date("2013-07-23 12:00:00").toString()   // Local noon
new Date("2013-07-23T12:00:00").toString()   // UTC noon
new Date("2013-07-23T12:00:00Z").toString()  // UTC noon
new Date("2013/07/23 12:00:00").toString()   // Local noon
```

There are many other inconsistencies.  For example, Chrome isn't even consistent within itself:

```
new Date("2013-07-23 00:00:00").toString()   // Local midnight
new Date("2013-07-23").toString()            // UTC midnight
```

If you need to parse dates from strings in a *consistent* manner, you should consider using a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

```
moment("2013-07-23 12:00:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format()     // Local noon
moment.utc("2013-07-23 12:00:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format() // UTC noon
```

The main advantage is that you can control the input and output formats, and it works the same way in all browsers.