# How to convert date in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I need to convert date '02-01-2017' to '2017-01-02'.How can I do this in angularjs.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format date in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

This should do,

```
var date = "02-01-2017";
var newdate = date.split("-").reverse().join("-");
console.log(newdate);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var date = "02-01-2017";
var newdate = date.split("-").reverse().join("-");
console.log(newdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular js date filters for this purpose. The date filter syntax is like

> {{ date | date : format : timezone }}

where format is your required format i.e, `yyyy-dd-MM` and timezone that you prefer. You can find examples for this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_date.asp) and documentation at 
[angular js website](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

In chrome you can directly use `new Date('02-01-2017');` but in firefox there are some compatibility issues so that the date string needs to be written as `new Date('02/01/2017');` this will support in chrome also. Your date time stamp needs to be "IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamp". You can find the details regarding the compatibility issues [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073368/why-does-this-javascript-not-work-in-firefox)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">

        <p>Date In Chrome {{ date | date:"yyyy-dd-MM" }}</p>
        <p>Date In FireFox {{ dateFF | date:"yyyy-dd-MM" }}</p>

    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('datCtrl', function ($scope) {
            var dateTimeString = '02-01-2017';
            $scope.date = new Date(dateTimeString);
            $scope.dateFF = new Date(dateTimeString.replace("-", "/"));
        });
    </script>

    <p>The date filter formats a date object to a readable format.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: invalid date string format for `new Date()`. try it in firefox for example ...returns `invalid date`. This answer fails cross browser

Comment: @charlietfl In firefox there are some compatibility issues so that the date string needs to be written as new Date('02/01/2017'); this will support in chrome also.

Comment: It's not a firefox issue, or even a browser issue...it's a spec issue of using invalid string format. And you have to parse the string to get that...which your edit does not do. You just magically made it appear in controller

Comment: It could be converted conditionally depending on the browser used.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever. It needs to be a valid string per Date docs. How are you going to test the many hundreds of possible browsers? You completely missed the whole point

Comment: the below line is replacing for ones like this 01/01-2017 dateTimeString.replace("-", "/") how to resolve this issue